# Unable to send response express api with lexruntime.postText(params)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-chatbot

I am trying to implement aws bot chat. for that I am using lexruntime. but post call return promise is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var request= lexruntime.postText(params)
  var result =   request.promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    request.on(
    'complete', function(response) {
      //   console.log("Always!");
      resolve(response.data)
    }
  )
.on('error', function(error,response) {
    console.log("went into Reject");
  reject(error)
})
 
}
  
  );
  try{ 
  nluresponse=  await result
   return (nluresponse)
  } catch(error){
    return (error);
  }
```